# what does "egli" refers to? "rubargli egli quando saranno più deboli"

Tags: word-meaning, word-order

the whole phrase is "sarò in grado di anticipare le loro mosse e rubargli egli quando saranno più deboli"

i have 2 assumptions:

1. "egli" is a continuation of "rubargli" (but actually i can't see the logic)
2. i've read that "egli" means "he", but probably in this case it means "they"

then

that's wrong with the word order? i mean shouldn't "quando" stay **before** "egli"?

Comment: To me this sentence means "I will be able to anticipate their moves and steal him when they are weaker". I'm not Italian so I'm waiting for an answer.

Comment: What's the source of this sentence, or at least when was it written? An expression like “rubargli egli etc.” looks to me either quite old or affected by a typo.

Comment: that's form "miraculous"
link: https://youtu.be/o_DaTwD5qTY?feature=shared
at ~ 27 sec

i relied on subs but..

Comment: It is a mistake in the subtitles. The man says 'rubarglieli', not 'rubargli egli'.

Comment: Probably this question may be closed, since it's based on a misconception.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about Italian language, but based on a misconception.